# JTable row background color not changing for Double or Integer

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am changing the background color of a row in JTable using following code. 
The color of row gets changed for all the cells which have String values however it does not gets changed for cells with Integer or Double values.

```
  private JTable getNewRenderedTable(final JTable table) {
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
                Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
                String status = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, index);
                if (Constants.seller.equals(status)) {
                    c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    //setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
                    c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
                }       
                return c;
            }   
        });
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: 1) `(String)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, index);` could be replaced by (the somewhat shorter) `(String)value;`  2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: It's debug yourself time! There are two possibilities at this point. Either `Constants.seller.equals(status)` is true when cell value is an Integer or it's not. In the first case that would be an interesting question, but we need that information to care. In the second case, your String casting must have somehow failed, or your Constants.seller is not equal to those numbers in which case everything works as expected

Comment: voting to close as too broad (Constants.seller.equals(status))

Comment: Won't the cast to `(String)` yield a `ClassCastException` for these types anyhow? You should probably just use `status = String.valueOf(value)`. Apart from that, the question lacks details nevertheless....

Comment: read Oracle tutorial How to use Tables - Concepts: Editors and Renderers, especially about standard Java data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register the same renderer also for Integer and Double. These classes have separate default renderer registered by default. Something like this.

```
private JTable getNewRenderedTable(final JTable table) {
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
            String status = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, index);
            if (Constants.seller.equals(status)) {
                c.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                //setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                c.setBackground(table.getBackground());
                c.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            }       
            return c;
        }   
    });
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Double.class, table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));
    return table;
}
```

Comment: `if (Constants.seller.equals(status)) {` <is ignored by> `Double/Number.class`